# Have issue with typed dataset nullable date value

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a `datatable` in a typed dataset with a date column
When I change the `NullValue` property to return `null` or `empty` , vs 2008 wont let me.

it says

> The value entered is not valid for the current data type.

I need to be able to set null values por this column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use typed datasets, you can define that the column is nullable (`AllowDBNull`) If this property is set to true, you can make use of the methods `yourDataRow.SetFieldnameNull()` and `yourDataRow.IsFieldnameNull()`   (of course, you have to replace `Fieldname` with the name of your nullable field)

Comment: How do I bind to this without throwing an exception??